# How to filter 1 table using other

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables:

```
TABLE1
----------------
query |  info
aa    |  info
bb    |  info
aa    |  info
cc    |  info
cc    |  info

TABLE2:
----------------
query |  info
aa    |  inf
cc    |  inf
```

Table 1 can have repeating queries, but 2 cannot

I need an SQL query to get all queries in table 1 that also exist in table 2. If there are multiple corresponding queries in table 1, then there should be multiple in the result
What is the simplest way to do this?

Comment: Can you post your expected results, and - more importantly - an example of any queries you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

```
 select * from table1 where table1.query in (select query from table2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select table_1.* from table_1 inner join table_2 on table_1.query = table_2.query
```